# Pick a price from database on intersection row and column

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

First of all, I'm new to PHP programming.

For the development of a webshop (windows blinds), I'm trying to create a price calculation form where the customer has to specify the height and width of the window. The form has to pick the right price out of the database.

This is a picture of how the example database looks like:

[image]

When the customer picks a height (1st column) and width (1st row), the script must look for the price where the two intersect (in this example it's 90).

[image]

Unfortunately I cannot find any tutorials, references or anything on this subject.

Can anyone please help me out by providing me links to tutorials, codes, or anything helpful?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's a picture of what a spreadsheet might look like. A database table is NOT a spreadsheet! Step one is to read up on normalization!

Comment: What if a window has 25x25 :)

Comment: Kevin have a look at my edit. You should change your table structure like @Strawberry suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The query should look something like this:

```
$width = "20";
$height = 30;

query("SELECT `" . quote($width) . "` FROM table WHERE Hoogte = " . quote($height));
```

Where `query` and `quote` are your mysql methods that you use to query the database and escape data.

If `Hoogte` is a string you have to alter the query like this:

```
query("SELECT `" . quote($width) . "` FROM table WHERE Hoogte = '" . quote($height) . "'");
```

**EDIT**

This query will return what you need, but you definitely should take your time optimizing your table. Have a look at normalization.

A possible table could be the following:

```
price
-------
id
value
height
width
```

And your query would then look like this:

```
query("SELECT value FROM price WHERE height = " . quote($height) . " AND width = " . quote($width));
```

With this you have no problem adding new height and width values without the need to alter you table!

Comment: @Strawberry: I'm sorry :(

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I've changed the table like you suggested in your comment and it works just fine.

The next question will be, what if a customer enters 25x25 (like the comment from DanFromGermany)? The displayed should be the one from 20x20..

Comment: @KevinHamer: Great! If it works, please consider marking the answer as the correct one.

Comment: Sorry, I had hit the enter button a little bit too fast ;)

Comment: @KevinHamer: Just add a new row with the value of 20,20 and the width and height of 25?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that the price of (for instance) window decorations with the dimensions 21x21 till 29x29 will be the same price as 20x20.

Comment: This is a complete new question. But you could work with ranges `WHERE width >= 20 AND width < 30 AND height >= 20 AND height < 30`. Or you just add for every possible value a row. This is the simplest way ...

Answer (score -1):

Well, I guess you might have two separate tables for this reasons.

But at the moment I may suggest the following:

Firstly, let's get the desired size. It is meant that the first size in the table is '10'. So, we are searching in the column '10' for the value '30':

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE 10 = '30';");
```

Once done, we need to get the result from that row. We do not need number from any other column rather than '60', right? So, we are trying to get a result from the column '60', like this:

```
$res = mysql_fetch_array($q);
$resultForColumn = $res['60'];
```

I guess the user might choose something other then 60, so you might change it anytime:

```
$i = $_POST['UserChosedSize']; // Do not forget to sanitize it, if you have something like this;
$resultForColumn = $res[$i];
```

Hope this helps.

UPD: Probably, Mr. Tobias Kun wrote it right and his example is much faster and easier.